# Word-wrap CSS property not affecting a table cell

Tags: css, css-tables, word-wrap

I have one long word...

`p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCx+wnDhlr7GqHiH6lAaPPuN5F7RjUrtvGyxxZkClJsLaTDeqg/FuJXU7RYdPQ2Ka++tfw0Z9+SRKatLUQQeCqLK8z1/V4p7BaJKPkegMzXgWGnFVmz1tdLFiYUGq0MvVgqWiepcTFmwgSd9g1pGRiCSDHJUDwcc+NidiW4/ixw4QIDAQAB"`

...that I am trying to fit in a table cell (`<td>`), for which I've tried using `word-wrap: break-word;` and the like to force the text to wrap, but none of them seem to have any affect on the text.

### ( **[HERE'S THE LIVE EXAMPLE](http://aahank.com/jots/2012/10/setting-up-google-apps-for-your-domain-with-amazon-route-53.html)** )

[image: Screenshot - Click To Enlarge!]
**Click on the image to enlarge!**

The text goes on and on horizontally, and doesn't wrap. Which CSS property am I supposed to be using here?

---

### THE CODE

```
<table>
     <thead>
          <tr>
                <th>Name
                </th><th>Type
                </th><th>Value
                </th><th>TTL
          </th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr>
                <td>wtnmail._domainkey.whatthenerd.com.</td>
                <td>TXT</td>
                <td>"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCx+wnDhlr7GqHiH6lAaPPuN5F7RjUrtvGyxxZkClJsLaTDeqg/FuJXU7RYdPQ2Ka++tfw0Z9+SRKatLUQQeCqLK8z1/V4p7BaJKPkegMzXgWGnFVmz1tdLFiYUGq0MvVgqWiepcTFmwgSd9g1pGRiCSDHJUDwcc+NidiW4/ixw4QIDAQAB"</td>
                <td>300</td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS

Based on j08691's answer, I am using this now:

```
table {
   table-layout: fixed;
   word-break: break-all;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And that's resulted in this:

[image: Screenshot - Click To Enlarge!]
**Click on the image to enlarge!**

Yes, the table isn't super stylish as it used to be, but now I can at least be sure that the data shows (even when the browser is resized i.e. smaller resolutions).

*Still looking for an elegant solution, if any.*

Comment: Can you please post the original code here or in a JSfiddle so that this question is useful to other people, once you've fixed the original page?

Comment: What sort of "elegant solution" are you looking for?  `text-overflow: ellipsis` or a jquery show/hide?

Comment: @Scrimothy One in which I don't have to use `table-layout:fixed;` for the table, or `word-break: break-word;` on a particular table cell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to your `word-wrap` rule on the cell, add the CSS rule `table-layout:fixed` to your table (and possibly a width).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FcVSc/)**

Comment: By the way, I ended up using this: `table { table-layout:fixed; word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word; }`

Answer (score 5):

`word-break: break-word;` worked for me on `.entry-content table td` while editing in Chrome's Inspector.

To apply it only to offending `td` cells, you could create a specific class and add it to the td's HTML:

```
.break-word {
    word-break: break-word; 
}
```

Comment: `word-break: break-word;` breaks every word in the table - I've tried it already.

Comment: Can you edit the table's HTML? You could create a .break-word class and just add it to the offending td.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a tip for anyone who still has problems with break-word: 
I had to add `white-space: normal` because it was set on 'nowrap'

Especially if you use bootstrap some elements like the labels have  `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: Had to add it to what element with what selector? You could improve your answer by adding the complete changes necessary.

Comment: This was so on point for me - `break-word` wasn't working due to bootstrap table styles

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that worked for me. I added it to my code as: 

    `.mdl-data-table {
      white-space: normal; /* else no automatic word wrapping possible */
    }`

Comment: The white-space change is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your text **is** wrapped - notice how it breaks after `k=rsa;` because you have a space there.  But there's no space in the `p=` value to break on.

However, you can add a `word-break: break-all;` specification to that element, which might be closer to what you're looking for.  See http://jsfiddle.net/zu6Eh/.