# Why does word-break work for tables but not word wrap?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Consider the following example:

```css
.table {
   width: 50px;
   display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}  

.table a {
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}

.table2 a {
  word-break: break-all; 
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <a href="#">doNotClickMedoNotClickMedoNotClickMedoNotClickMe</a>  
</div>  

<div class="table table2">
  <a href="#">doNotClickMedoNotClickMedoNotClickMedoNotClickMe</a>  
</div>
```

As you can see in first table `word-wrap` could not break the text to new line. But in second table `word-break` could break the text. As far as I understand from mdn articles on [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) and [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) the only difference between them is that `word-break` cause even chinese and japanese language text to break whereas `word-wrap` doesn't work on those languages. Now how come that `word-break` can break word in tables but `word-wrap` not? Does html css spec mention this behavior?

Reading some other similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1258416/3429430), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5889508/3429430) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12694941/3429430), another thing that I found unordinary is why does adding `table-layout: fixed` to table allow `word-wrap` to break words?

Comment: Seems like the behavior of `word-break` is different in firefox. I posted the question while using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `table-layout: fixed` worked here because for

> `table-layout: fixed` :- The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells.(can cause an overflow in the cells if  `word-wrap:break-word` is not set)

and for

> `table-layout: auto` :- The column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells irrespective of column width.

so the  `word-wrap:break-word` which is now `overflow-wrap:break-word`( in CSS3 ) does not allow the content to overflow by breaking the contents as the `table-layout: fixed`.

The above explanation is partial for your question but I hope it will somehow help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But to me the explanation is rather contradicting... _(can cause an overflow in the cells)_ seems to imply that text will overflow not wrap.

Comment: Thank u, This line  _(cause an overflow in the cells)_  means that if you set `word-wrap:break-word` then text will be wrapped otherwise overflow will occur in case of `table-layout: fixed`.